# Different home page before signin in rails app rather then login page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

[image]

Here, whenever i try to open localhost:3000 it automatically changes into localhost:3000/users/sign_in and login form gets appear. But i don't want this login form when i enter localhost:3000. I simply want all content except form at first and when i press login or signup links, corresponding form should only be displayed.

Here is code for my application controller that renders my home page:-

```
 protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  layout :layout_by_resource

  protected

  def layout_by_resource
    if !user_signed_in?
      "home"
    else
      "dashboard"
    end
  end
```

so can anybody help me to solve this problem. I am using devise gem for user login.

Comment: Show controller's code that render this home page (root page)

Comment: ok i have included my application controllers code

Comment: what's an action name for home page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either (1) your root url is set to the new session page or (2) you're being redirected to the new session page because your root url is secured by a `before_action` that requires the user to login.

(1) In `config/routes.rb`, you may have set your root page to the new session page:

```
root to: "session#new"
```

(2) If not, you're being redirected away from your root route.

What does the root route point to? Let's suppose for the purpose of this example that it points to `"home#index"`:

```
root to: "home#index"
```

Then you'll want to check in the appropriate controller and controller action (in this case, `HomeController#index`) to see if you're enforcing authentication there.

Here's what that what might look like:

```
# app/controllers/home_controller.rb

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end
end
```

You'll want to make sure that `before_action` is not applied to the controller action pointed to by the root route:

```
# app/controllers/home_controller.rb

class HomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: :index

  def index
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Very simple. You use a normal home#index template and redirect to sign_in for devise. if you want form on same page use render. 
When you go to localhost:3000 and you are redirected than you have either root to sign_in or some controller code that redirects to sign in when not signed in. Just change that+